# Poetry: how to reinstall a wheel with the same name

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am using poetry to manage the dependencies of my python project and I am really a fan of it!
At the moment one of the dependencies of my project is the wheel coming from an internal library, since it is internal this has then to be installed from a wheel.
Lately I did some changes on the library and I wanted to test them on my project, I then produced a wheel and then moved the wheel in the location where the pyproject.toml was expecting it to be.
I then executed a poetry install but I noticed later that the code inside my venv was still the same as the previous one.
In order to update the code corresponding to the new wheel I need to remove the reference to that package in the pyproject.toml file, then update, then read the wheel to the pyproject.toml file and then update again.

Is there a way to force reinstall the packages on poetry? I tried to look it up but I did not find any information about it.
In other case, is someone else facing more or less the same workflow using poetry and can suggest a better way to handle it?

Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I've been looking for the same thing. Best way I found is to have a script in the package folder

```
poetry remove <package-name> && poetry add <path_to_wheel>
```

Comment: Hi! yes I have the same tactic but it is in general difficult to select which package I want to remove and which one I want to keep.
For the moment this problem does not present too much because I deploy from a fresh machine where I need to install everything, but a more stable solution has to be found... maybe comparing the sha256 of the packages and poetry should be able to spot if I am trying to reinstall a package already installed or a new version of the same!
Thank you very much for your answer!